# Cells in table view not being displayed

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am using a UITableView in one of my view controllers and am using a custom class called ListCell. The table view and the cells are being displayed, but the content in the cells are not being displayed, so the cell is empty. But if I press the cell it performs its task. So the content is there but its not being displayed. I think it has something to do with how I registered the class to the custom type ListCell. Here is how I declared it in viewDidLoad...

```
self.tblListView.registerClass(ListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Is there something wrong with the above line. And what it is causing the cell content to not being displayed?

Also I tried enabling size classes and that did not work. Also all the cells are being created programmatically.

The below line of code is responsible for displaying the cell data.

```
cell.displayAlertData(mutArrAlertList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

the thing is mutArrAlertList's object at the first index is an optional type Optional(Temperature). I think the only way this will work if it is not optional. The object is being passed my a push notification, and what the push notification sends is not optional. So somewhere it randomly turns into an optional type. Is there a way I can get rid of that optional value around it?

Here is cell for row method:

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier: String = "Cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ListCell

    //if cell == nil
    //{
        //let nib: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ListCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        //cell = (nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? ListCell)!

    //}

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    print("")
    print("This is cell: \(mutArrAlertList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! [NSObject : AnyObject])") //did this to check what the value is and it is an optional

    cell.displayAlertData(mutArrAlertList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! [NSObject : AnyObject])

    if indexPath.row == mutArrAlertList.count-1
    {
        if ApplicationDelegate.intPage > mutArrAlertList.count
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationDelegate.intPage = ApplicationDelegate.intPage + 10
            self.reloadDataFromdb()

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Storyboard?

Comment: I created a UITableView in storyboard, but not the cells

Comment: Have you tried to use the Table View Cell?

Comment: I will edit my question and post what I think is wrong

Comment: show me CellForRow method, I will solve your issue. @Harshil.Chokshi

Comment: OK posting cellForRow method